# Determine center point of an offset arc

Tags: math, geometry

I am working on an algorithm which requires the coordinates for the center point of an offset arc. Dimensions available to find this are shown in the image below and the dimension required is labeled as X:
[image]
The point at the very left of the arc is a quadrant therefore, the arc center also 2.27 away from the line with a dimension of 3. The actual value of x in this example is 2.47 (rounded), this was found using CAD however, I am trying to find an mathematical relation for this.

Also, please note that dimensions shown are just what are available and not necessarily what are needed to find the center point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consider that top arc end is vertical (adjoint with straight line).
Let's denote segments

```
2.27 = B
4.5-3=1.5 = A
x = R = A + t     //arc radius
R^2 = B^2 + t^2   //Pythagor's rule
(A + t)^2 = B^2 + t^2
t = (B^2 - A^2)/ (2*A)
t = 0.967 here
x = R = A + t = 1.5 + 0.967 = 2.467
```

end formula:

```
x = A + (B^2 - A^2)/ (2*A) = (A^2 + B^2)/ (2*A)
```

Comment: +1 nice (I overlooked that triangle) my solution from circle equation get the same result